# ConcurrentLinkedDeque in API below 21

Tags: java, android, concurrency, classnotfoundexception

In order to resolve a concurrency issue, I'm using [`ConcurrentLinkedDeque`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html) which according to android documentation, is added in **API-21**.

However, I'm still able to run the code on a device with **API-16** without any errors at all. Though it does highlight calls to its methods saying:

> Call requires API level 21 (current min is 14):
>   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedDeque#ConcurrentLinkedDeque

but that can be ignored using `@SuppressLint("NewApi")`.

So, why is it possible? Why don't I get a `ClassNotFoundException` when running it in APIs below 21?

Comment: you need to analyze the **git logs** on android.googlesource.com ... this class is there from the time when android started supporting java 7 but google "unhide" it in API 16

Comment: It seems it is there, just that it was not considered to be ready for App Code. For example I have found it for Android 4.4. on [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.4_r1-robolectric-1/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.java#ConcurrentLinkedDeque)

Comment: Did you figure out if you can use ConcurrentLinkedDeque in API below 21?

Comment: @Paulo I simply stopped using that :)